# Counting Operations of Merge Sort and Selection Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I want to compare count of operations of the sorting algorithms Merge Sort and Selection Sort, but I have some problems figuring out which operations to count and which not..

Here are my implementations. I think I'm counting the operations of Selection Sort in the right way, but I don't know about Merge Sort:

Selection Sort:

```
public class SelectionSort {
private int exchanges, comparisons;

public void selectionSort(int[] x) {    
    for (int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<x.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] > x[j]) 
            {
                //... Exchange elements
                int temp = x[i];
                x[i] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;
                exchanges++;
            }
            comparisons++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("SelSort_Exchanges: "+exchanges);
    System.out.println("SelSort_Comparisons: "+comparisons);
    System.out.println("SelSort_Operations: "+(exchanges+comparisons));
}
}
```

If I put in an array of 10 int I get:

```
SelSort_Comparisons: 45
SelSort_Exchanges: 27
SelSort_Operations: 72
```

Seems right to me, but now for Merge Sort:

```
public class Mergesort {
private int[] numbers;
private int[] helper;

private int number;
private int comparisons, exchanges;

public void sort(int[] values) {
    this.numbers = values;
    number = values.length;
    this.helper = new int[number];
    mergesort(0, number - 1);
    System.out.println("MerSort_Comparisons "+comparisons);
    System.out.println("MerSort_Exchanges "+exchanges);
    System.out.println("MerSort_Operations "+(comparisons+exchanges));
    System.out.println();
}

private void mergesort(int low, int high) {
    // Check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
    if (low < high) 
    {
        // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        // Sort the left side of the array
        mergesort(low, middle);
        // Sort the right side of the array
        mergesort(middle + 1, high);
        // Combine them both
        merge(low, middle, high);
    }
}

private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

    // Copy both parts into the helper array
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        helper[i] = numbers[i];
        exchanges++;
    }
    int i = low;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = low;
    // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
    // to the original array
    while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
        if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
            numbers[k] = helper[i];
            i++;
            exchanges++;
        } else {
            numbers[k] = helper[j];
            j++;
            exchanges++;
        }
        k++;
        comparisons++;

    }
    // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
    while (i <= middle) {
        numbers[k] = helper[i];
        exchanges++;
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}   
}
```

now I get

```
MerSort_Comparisons 22
MerSort_Exchanges 61
MerSort_Operations 83
```

as a result but I don't know if its right. Result of Comparisons seems right to me, but if I take an array of 20 for example it doesnt seem right anymore.

Could anyone help me with this and tell me where exactly I have to put my comparison and exchange increments?

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: An array with 10 elements will hardly give good indication on algorithm performance. To get a better feeling of how they perform under different inputs, try comparing larger arrays (say, 1000) elements, in various flavors: randomized, already sorted, reversed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to create two methods, `Compare` and `Swap`, and increase counter inside of them. Whatever [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) you implement, it should only interact with the array using these methods.

Also, [this page](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) can help you analyze different sorting algorithms visually.